# 自動デプロイ時にエラーがでる: failed to load command: cap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano

railsでアプリを作成して、awsへ自動デプロイをしようとしています

自動デプロイをしようと下記を実行したところ

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

以下のエラーが発生してしまいます

```
bundler: failed to load command: cap (/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/cap)
Gem::Exception: can't find executable cap for gem capistrano. capistrano is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
  /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/cap:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

gemやバージョン関係のエラーと考えていますが、どういったエラーなのでしょうか？
過去に余計にエラーを発生させてしまったことがあり、確信を持てないままデバッグするのが怖く、質問させていただきました

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.5.2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.7'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # gem 'capistrano'
  # gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  # gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  # gem 'capistrano-rails'
  # gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem "font-awesome-sass"
gem 'ancestry'
# gem 'fog-aws'

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn', '5.4.1'
end
```

Comment: `bundle install` なさっていますか？

Comment: はい、やっております

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/295050

Comment: 問題が解決している場合は、[回答を承認して質問を解決済みにして](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/32986)いただけませんか？

Comment: すみません、使い方がよく分からず失念していました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

capistrano がインストールされていないため、`cap` がロードできないというエラーが起こっています。

Gemfile をよく見ると capistrano の行はコメントアウトされており、`bundle install` しても capistrano がインストールされていません。Gemfile を見直してください。

```rb
# gem 'capistrano'
```